# adding a third subnet on the same router

Tags: networking, subnet

cisco 2800 series 
(isp cross connect)Eth0/0 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.252,  Eth0/1 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.224

```
##Eth0/1.1 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.128 <--- want to add this block in!##
```

I've been granted a new subnet /25 and want to add this to my existing CS2800 router.

I've tried creating a sub-interface Eth0/1.1 and as soon as i finish the configuration and do no shutdown about to 1-3 hours later my VMs begin to go offline and eventually everything goes down except the routers IPs which allows me to login and disable int0/1.1 which in turn everything comes back online.

i am currently trying to input the subnet as a secondary IP some have suggested but still no solution since i am not able to use the IP range.

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
description connection to NETWORK 107.18.19.28
ip address 107.18.19.30 255.255.255.252
ip broadcast-address 107.18.19.31
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
description connection to NETWORK 107.18.19.28
ip address 64.72.69.129 255.255.255.128 secondary
ip address 107.18.19.65 255.255.255.224
ip broadcast-address 107.18.19.95
duplex auto
speed auto
!
ip default-gateway 107.18.19.29
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 107.18.19.29
```

Comment: A /25 subnet should use the mask 255.255.255.128

Comment: Did you try to assign the new subnet as secondary address to Eth0/1, instead of usung subinterfaces?

Comment: yes i did try that also but no luck ....what is strange is that i can ping the first 2 IPs on the new subnet block even tho its not assigned to any server or device. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this new subnet?  Are you assigning the new IP addresses directly to server or is there a firewall or other device doing NAT?  Maybe a network diagram would help?

Comment: currently i have 2 subnets assigned to me and i am using Eth0/0 for /30 and Eth0/1 for /27 .....since i am running out of IPs i am granted a new block of IPs /25 and would like to add this to my existing cisco2800 router. iv tried the sub-int 0/1.1 option(brings down my network) and iv tried the secondary option which seems to not even take effect or change to my network bc i assign an IP from the block to a VM but no response or ping.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear to me why you tried to setup a sub-interface.  I suspect you just need to add this as just another secondary.

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
  ip address 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.128 secondary
```

Comment: CORRECT! i am simply trying to include this subnet my existing setup which is listed above. i tried the sub-int option bc i read online/research that you can do this. i disregarded the sub-int option and have implemented the secondary IP option but no effect or change has taken place to my network....is there a reason?

Comment: What change are you expecting to take effect?  Adding an additional network, adds another network.  After that you would need to assign IP addresses from that network to a machine so you can use it.  Or you need to add it to your DHCP server or something.

Comment: You say it doesn't work but you don't give enough detail to troubleshoot the problem. You stated that ping doesn't work but you don't say what you're pinging and from where. Can you ping the secondary ip address of the router from a device in the same ip address range connected to that interface (via a switch)? Can the router ping a device in that ip address range from the correct source ip address on that interface (using the extended ping command on the router)?

Comment: ip address 64.72.69.129 255.255.255.128 secondary <---- this is the subnet i am trying to add on top of my existing setup. when i try to assign and ping any ip from its range 64.72.69.131-254 it does not respond...@zordache, the effect i want is to use the IPs from this subnet. @joeqwerty, no ping is possible even tho i create a VM and assign from the possible range noted above. these IPs are not internal their public granted to me by a datacenter for use. thanks

Comment: @joeqwerty, no ping is NOT possible even tho i create a VM and assign from the possible range noted above. these IPs are not internal their public granted to me by a datacenter for use. thanks